# Preserve stack traces in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to preserve the call stack when handling errors that comes from e.g. net.js.

The example below works but requires me to pre-allocate an error object for every call which is not optimal.

```
function socketStuff(callback) {

  // ..

  var maybeError = new Error 'Socket error ';
  socket.on('error', function(error) {
    maybeError.message += error.message;
    callback(maybeError);
  });
}
```

Is there any way to prepend the stack that i get from creating an error in the function's context to the error i get from the socket without having to create an error object beforehand?

Comment: You're not preserving call stacks, you have an aggregate message for all error messages. If you want to keep stack traces - NodeJS has long stack traces for event emitters. Also for example some promise libraries (Like Bluebird or Q) have long stack traces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have to acquire the stack trace up front, at the point of your `new Error()` call. You don't have to create an actual Error object; you can also use [the V8 stack trace API](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi) to do it:

```
var stackHolder = {};
Error.captureStackTrace(stackHolder, nameOfCurrentFunction);
```

and now the stack is available as `stackHolder.stack`.

V8 lazy-formats the stack so this isn't as expensive as you might think; that `stack` property is actually a property getter which the first time it's run does the formatting work and then replaces itself with the output. (From the docs linked above: "For efficiency stack traces are not formatted when they are captured but on demand, the first time the stack property is accessed.")

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of existing long stack traces library, for example [this one](https://github.com/tlrobinson/long-stack-traces)