# Adding Stack Trace Reference to Existing, Context-Less Error Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I've been getting the occasional error returning from a library call, however the stack trace of the error doesn't keep the full stack trace, thus making it hard to find out *exactly* where this is cropping up from.

I'd like to figure out a way of adding a reference to where / what file this error's stack trace is being accessed from.  I might not be able to catch the top-level function name, but even then if I could get the line numbers of the error handler, it would be enough to point me in the right direction.

After tinkering with it, I believe I might have a fairly hacky solution that may work (though it's untested in my production environment).

```
var addStackFrame = function(e) {
  var splitStack = e.stack.split("\n");

  // We splice from the 3rd element to drop
  // the error name, and addStackFrame() reference.
  var thisLine = new Error().stack
                  .split("\n")
                  .slice(2, 3)
                  .join('\n');

  e.stack = [splitStack[0], thisLine]
            .concat(splitStack.slice(1))
            .join("\n");

  return e;
};
```

This logs adds last three methods that were called to the Error object's stack trace.

I also have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22521285/23875) that suggests there might be a native V8 way of implementing this, which I would be much more interested in using.

Is a native way of adding references to a stack trace of an existing Error object?  Barring that, is there a more elegant way of handling of adding context to a stack trace?

Comment: More information for future viewers, the link to the [JavaScriptStackTraceApi is here.](https://code.google.com/p/v8-wiki/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi)  My hacky solution ended up allowing me to find where these errors were coming back from, however this solution is far from perfect.